# How to Using if Else statement in Array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

im trying create if else statement, but not working,

this is  my code

```
$selected = (array) $_POST[gejala];
if($selected == "1"):
    print_msg('Belum ada gejala terpilih. <a href="?m=konsultasi">Kembali</a>');
else:
    print_msg('agsjhdgashjgdajhsgd');
```

when im select 1 data but not displaying print_msg...

print_r when im select 2 data

```
Array
(
    [m] => hasil
    [gejala] => Array
        (
            [0] => G014
            [1] => G015
        )

)
```

Comment: Could you please share you form code here?

Comment: did you var_dump($selected) check what you get

Comment: you should add `'` around gejala - `$selected = $_POST['gejala'];`

Comment: yeah, im try select 1 data, displaying array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "G016" }

Comment: @Philipp still not working

Comment: @mageDev0688 https://github.com/jazuly/code/blob/master/konsultasi.php

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen you form code you are posting multiple input fields values, so you need to run `foreach` loop get the every input fields value.

Please use the below code hope this will help:

```
$gejala = $_POST['gejala'];

foreach($gejala as $value) {

   $gejala = $value;
   if($gejala == "1"){
        print_msg('Belum ada gejala terpilih. <a href="?m=konsultasi">Kembali</a>');
   }else{
       print_msg('agsjhdgashjgdajhsgd');
   }
}
```

Comment: i got this error :  syntax error, unexpected '}' in

Comment: See the updated answer. and try with the above answer.

Comment: not working, always displaying `else message` that just looping `else message`

Comment: Edit your question and show me the array print values here like this: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);` add this code in your file where you are posting the form data.

Comment: What you have inserted in your table column `kode_gejala`  is it just ID or any other value?

Comment: Accept my answer now, :)

Comment: What is the problem ? you have get answer of the particular,